# Why is the helicopter rotor brake easily accessible?

Tags: safety, helicopter

[According to this article](https://www.aerotime.aero/articles/grand-canyon-pilot-terrified-passenger-grabs-rotor-brake), a rotor brake is dangerous to use in-flight, yet it's easily accessible and the pilot's reaction indicates that it would've deployed mid-flight. Why is the brake so easily accessible and deployable during flight if it's such a safety hazard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is it easily accessible? Well simply because it's intended to be.

When you consider the main usage of this system, it it to allow the pilot to expedite the slowing down and stopping of the main rotor on the ground, usually to allow safe ingress/egress of the passengers. If it wasn't easily accessible by the pilot it wouldn't serve it's purpose.

There is a question here of whether a helicopter such as this, where it is easily reachable from a passenger seat is a suitable aircraft to take tourists, or anyone untrustworthy around the primary controls of an aircraft. I think sometimes people are just a little dumb around things they don't understand - ie/ I'm almost sure nobody is stupid enough to pull on a car handbrake at highway speeds - but that's primarily because they *understand the implications*.

In any case, the helicopter engine is likely to have had well enough power to overcome the application of the rotor brake (similar to your car engine being able to overcome the power of the hand brake if youve ever accidentally pulled away with it on). The problem comes if the pilot needed full power at that exact moment they may not have had it all available if stupid tourist pulled the brake.

Pilot conclusion: Make sure you fully brief lay passengers before letting them within reaching distance of primary controls while airborne. You're taught this on day one. The passenger here was dumb, the pilot was negligent!

Comment: Thank you. Wouldn't placing the brake on the left side of the pilot be a simple yet vastly safer option?

Comment: Or have a 'squat' sensor like fixed-wing aircraft gear?

Comment: @AhmedTawfik Both options sounds sensible to me. Does make you wonder why the designer didnt do it, right?

Comment: Agreed, hence the question :)

Comment: @Jamiec Is the linkage mechanical? If so, perhaps moving it to the left of the pilot would be difficult or impossible?

Comment: It's not clear what type of helicopter this is, but bear in mind many helicopter designs are fundamentally still 1960s-80s, fully mechanical, with simply updated avionics and engines. There probably wasn't any consideration for having untrained people in the front seat.